# Twilio not delivering sms messages to some users

Tags: sms, twilio

I set up a scheduling website at work which uses [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) to send out sms messages with each person's next day assignment information as well as a link to the website where notes and everyone's next-day assignment is posted.  Occasionally colleagues complain that they haven't received messages.  Recently the problem has gotten much worse though is to be limited to people with AT&T and Sprint.  People with Verizon and TMobile are get their messages without a problem.

A few more facts:

- All of my code works well in testing and is consistent with Twilio's
  instructions.
- Twilio's logs list the messages as having been sent.
- The people who's sms messages are not delivered tend to be at the end
  of the alphabet

Anyone have any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SMS messages the twilio logs show as sent which never arrive at the recipient's phone may be filtered by cell phone carriers as part of an effort to reduce spam sms messages.  A website that sends out a batch of messages like the scheduling website you (I) describe may be particularly susceptible to such filtering since spam is also sent out in batches.  The fact that recipients at the end of the alphabet tend to be blocked rather than those at the beginning might reflect an algorithm which flags earlier messages as suspicious and blocks subsequent ones that appear similar in that they contain the same website link.

In the past I was able to solve this problem by adding a 1 second delay between messages.  That worked fine for my purposes.  My site sent out the messages as a background job and with the 1 second delay about 25 sms messages get sent out over 2 minutes.

More recently AT&T and Sprint started blocking many more messages, though not all.  At Jan 11, 15:04 PST, [Twilio's status](http://status.twilio.com/) was aware of the problem and noted:

> Identified - Messages with hyperlinks to goo.gl are being filtered on AT&T and Sprint. We are working with these carriers to address this filtering.

I was able to get around this problem by creating a shortened url using [Bitly](https://bitly.com/) instead of [Google's url shortening service](https://goo.gl/).

Of note, Twilio is a great service but in the past their support folks were unaware that spam filtering could be blocking some of my sms messages.  That's my prime motivation for posting about this issue here.

It seems that sites like mine can get caught in the crossfire between sms spammers and wireless carriers attempting to block them.  Hopefully some day such sms spam filtering will get more sophisticated and stop blocking the messages sent by sites like mine.

I would love to hear if anyone with more sophisticated insight than mine has any comments.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this in depth answer after you found out what was going on. Sorry you got caught in this filtering issue and glad to hear that using Bitly has fixed the problem for now.

Comment: I am facing similar problem. My A2P and use-case registration is approved. But I still can't get messages to Rogers in Canada. In logs, it shows as delivered but the number never receives it. Also is there a way to test messages to all popular US and Canada carriers? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Currently experiencing a really bad carrier filtering case through Twilio. Most messages sent to Verizon numbers are being blocked. According to Twilio support, Verizon recently implemented additional filtering methods to block A2P (Application-to-Peer) traffic.

Given this article: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/11/att-verizon-try-to-prevent-ban-on-text-message-blocking/ it seems like Verizon's more aggressive filtering might be related to the recent repeal of Net Neutrality, and their goal is to make more money by forcing businesses to get a short code.

Comment: Yes I was just notified by Twilio Support that the same thing was happening to our account.

Answer (score 1):

If your using 10 digit phone numbers I Would also look at this

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/short-codes/why-would-i-want-a-short-code-instead-of-sending-sms-from-a-regular-us-phone-number-or-phone-numbers

Long codes are meant for person-to-person communications, and can send only 1 message per second. For high-volume, application-driven messaging, Twilio recommends using a short code. Short codes can send SMS and MMS at 30 messages per second, and this high throughput is perfect for applications needing to send time-sensitive messages to many users at once. Furthermore, since carriers vet and approve all short codes for their intended use, they are not subject to carrier filtering or suspension for heavy traffic.

Comment: Interesting point about short codes, @StevenDStanton.  They would definitely solve filtering issues.  Still, random short codes (as opposed to vanity short codes) start at $5500/year.  That's not realistic for my little department's scheduling app.  It might be useful for other applications, though. Grateful you pointed them out.